# Adding third party reference dll's to C# project

Tags: c#, winforms, odp.net

I'm working on C# winforms project which connects to Oracle DB via ODP. I included `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` file for accessing `ODP`. I created a folder named references under the solution folder near the projects and included it from the necessary projects under the solution. I also made the dll as include under properties->publish->application files of main project. But when i deploy the applicaton to another computer it throws exception as:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Any suggestion how i can handle this please?

Comment: That is 3pty component, that can have some dependencies even on unmanaged dll, registry settings, etc. All I can think about is to somehow include running oracle data access install package before you deploy your application.

Comment: Check the version number that is deployed also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the Oracle.DataAccess Assembly is indeed in place on the system. It might well be that something failed in your installation process.

If it is in place, and you still get the error, you will need to install the Oracle client on this system. ODP is just a wrapper using the client. It will not enable a system without an Oracle client to access an Oracle database as far as I remember.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the Oracle client must be installed on the target system for this component to work properly. That was the case when I last used it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your dll to see which dependencies its missing.